# Swipe not working reliably on Xcode 6.3 beta; how to workaround?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I have a apple watch app (in simulator) which used to swipe without problems between pages, but I noticed that in Xcode 6.3 beta this is unreliable (I raised a bug 19781821).  Did anyone else have this problem or a workaround?

Since posting my original question, the bug has been (silently) fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta 3 (it was not mentioned in release notes).  Using later versions including the Gold Master also work correctly.

This question is left now mainly to serve to document this past problem.

[image: Setup showing three simple pages as a page-based workflow]

Comment: Since Xcode 6.3 is beta I suggest you wait until it is released before you use it for development. The beta is more ment to check and get feedback.

Comment: As this is WatchKit app not using a beta isn't possible.

Comment: Well you can use Xcode 6.2 with the iOS 8.2 beta, which is ment for WatchKit Apps. Xcode 6.3 is voor swift 1.2 preview.

Comment: The bug has been (silently) fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta 3 (it was not mentioned in release notes).  I don't know how best to adjust this question in the system (should I close it?)

Comment: @FaisalMemon: Edit your question to say what your comment said.